# Disable computer login, while still allowing web authentication to AD

Tags: active-directory

I was wondering if it was possible to still allow web applications to authenticate (ASP.Net authentication with windows forms pointing to AD)  while disabling the account from logging into the physical on campus terminal computers.

Thank you.
-Devin

Comment: if not log-in, how will he/she see the web application?

Comment: Externally authenticated AD. The application is in DMZ, a binding authentication occurs internally, and a SAML style authorization occurs. 
So... They can see the application just fine without logging in to an on Campus computer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest futzing with the userWorkstations attribute.  Set their account to some non-existant or benign workstation.  I haven't tested this myself, so you might find you need to specify some IIS servers (or else the account will be locked out of that as well).

Hope this helps.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/02/17/how-can-i-specify-the-computers-a-user-can-use-to-log-on-to-the-domain.aspx

Comment: I'm going to try that out. Its a rather clever solution. Let you know if it works as soon as I do.